# Editor Window Docked or does NOT Exist

Tags: delphi

I receive this Error message **Editor Window Docked or does NOT Exist** when attempting to enter in full-screen mode while using Delphi 10.2 Tokyo and [CnPack/CnWizards](https://github.com/cnpack/cnwizards).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what was happening.

The code editor window is docked by default in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo while using Default, Debug or Startup Layout.

To use full screen mode you should undock everything.

Select Classic Undocked in the ComboBox, after Help option in the Toolbar. This will undock every screen and the you can use full screen.

However, it is a bit weird to let everything undocked. What I did so while using two monitors was to drag the code editor to the second monitor. And then in the first monitor I started dragging and docking windows to let them get together. Then I saved this as a new layout.

To save as a new Layout go to: Toolbar --> View --> Desktops --> Save Desktop --> Type a name hit save.